# Error "Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'" when using "@google-cloud/storage" with Next.js 13 app dir

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, next.js, compiler-errors

I'm working on a Next.js 13 project and I'm trying to integrate Google Cloud Storage into it using the `@google-cloud/storage` library. However, when I attempt to build my project, I'm encountering an error related to the "fs" module. The error message I'm getting is as follows:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js
./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/transfer-manager.js
./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
./utils/GcpUtils.tsx
./src/components/Product/UnlockProductButton.tsx
./src/components/Product/SingleProductDisplay.tsx
./src/app/products/[productId]/page.tsx
```

I've followed the documentation for integrating Google Cloud Storage with Node.js and it appears that the error is originating from the library's internal dependencies. I understand that the "fs" module is a built-in Node.js module that deals with file system operations, but as of Next.js 13, server-side modules like "fs" can't be used directly in the browser.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. Installed the **`@google-cloud/storage`** package using npm.
2. Integrated the package into my application, specifically in a utility file (**`GcpUtils.tsx`**).
3. Used the utility file in various components, including **`UnlockProductButton.tsx`** and **`SingleProductDisplay.tsx`**.

I've reviewed the documentation provided by Next.js regarding the error **[here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found)**, but I'm unsure how to address this issue within the context of using the **`@google-cloud/storage`** library.

Has anyone else encountered this problem when using Google Cloud Storage with Next.js 13, and if so, what steps can I take to resolve this "fs" module error and successfully build my application?

Any insights, solutions, or workarounds would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

**Additional Context:**

- GcpUtils.tsx:

  ```
  const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  const storage = new Storage({
      keyFilename: '<service-key.json>',
  });

  const bucketName = '<bucketName>';
  const subfolderName = '<folder>';

  export async function UploadVideoFile(newFileName: string, file: File) {
      try {
          const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
          const renamedFile = bucket.file(`/${subfolderName}/${newFileName}.mp4`);

          await renamedFile.save(file, {
              contentType: 'video/mp4',
          });

          console.log('File uploaded successfully.');
      } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
          throw error;
      }
  }
  ```
- UnlockProductButton.tsx:

  ```
  function uploadFile(file: File) {
          const type = file.type;
          const sizeInMb = file.size / (1024 * 1024)
          if (type === "video/mp4") {
              if (sizeInMb < 20) {
                  setUploadedFile(true);
                  UploadVideoFile('test', file)
                      .then(() => {
                          setUploadedFile(false);
                          onClose();
                      })
                      .catch(console.error);
              } else {
                  console.log("File is too big! " + sizeInMb + "MB")
              }
          }
      }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found my error was due to trying to use GCS (Google Cloud Storage) from a client-side component. All interactions with GCS must be done on the server.